# overwrite U-boot code?

Tags: arm, u-boot

On AMVv7, I use U-boot as my bootloader.

### Question

Once it has initialized my board, and put itself in the ram, can my code overwrite it?
(I will provide my vector table, my TLB logic and so on).

I read that a cpu reset won't need the full initialization u-Boot does.

The plan is to use U-boot and to ditch it completely once it has done its work (saving me to do it in the first place) and take full control of the board, without sacrificing any bit of ram.

What is the problem with that approach (if there is one)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is fine.  This is for example how the Linux kernel operates as (generally speaking) nothing of U-Boot is around after U-Boot starts execution of whatever it has been told to load and execute.

Answer (score 1):

If your application capable of handling your board functionality,then no need of worrying about u-boot, because once it execute **load and execute**, this RAM location is usable memory.

If you run your standalone program under u-boot program space, it cannot be overwrite by your program. if you try to overwrite, the board will reboot.

Comment: Thanks Thiru. Yes the code is capable to manage the events and so on. Should I have a problem with some disabled features i don't want to reenable myself during a reboot, I will revert to a dynamic u-boot loading strategy that I will overwrite -again- later.